# Hiding the next to next child element using jquery

Tags: jquery

Say I have the below HTML

```
<div id="target">
    <div>
   <div></div>   //hide this one 
   </div>  
    ...
</div>
```

How can I hide the second div .$('#target').children().hide(); will hide starting the first .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want:

```
$('#target div div').hide();
```

Select the **div inside the div** inside `#target`.

Comment: I think as a general rule it is best to get as close as possible to the desired element using selectors

Comment: It just depends on the use case and what you know in advance. More general solutions exist that compute the children of `#target`, but why have the computer figure it out if you already know it?

Answer (score 0):

And if you need to do this with css

```
#target > div div:first-child {display:none;}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aMs7d/)